# How to restrict people from entering directories on server

Tags: apache

A simple google search can reveal alot on server.
ex "index of parent directory"

1. How can I avoid people from entering server directory. Ex link   59.181.118.41/files/headfirst/
2. sometimes When I try to browse such directory, I get 403 error saying forbidden or access  denied. 
   But it is still possible to access to access files if url is entered which can be revealed using google. 
   Ex. filetype:pdf site:link

ps I am not familiar with apache and web servers so please explain a bit and how stuff work and why this happens

Answer (score 2):

The best approach to is not put the directory under the webroot in the first place.

The webroot is where you put things to be served over HTTP. If you never want it served over HTTP, don't put it there.

---

Alternatively, [deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) from all.

---

Another option would be to set the permissions on the file system so that the web server user wasn't allowed to read the files.

Comment: With the latter one being the most secure option which also holds if your sites server side code gets exploited, unless they can localroot you.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said, don't put the directories there. And to expand on his answer on the deny part, add the following to your host entry.

```
<Directory /my/directory/here>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

The directory name is case sensitive and should be an absolute path. You can add as many of these as you need, and they will cover all sub-directories underneath it as well.

Would also read up on the access controls apache allows [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).